# How to make a map made with Google Javascript Map API load and not stay white

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I am trying to add a map to my website using google maps javascript APi.
I followed the tutorial they have on their website. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
The map appears on my website but for some reason its not loading.

I tried activating the API.

```
    <div id="map">

    </div>
    <script>
        function initMap(){
            var home = {lat: 43.452969, lng: -80.495064};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementByID("map"),{zoom: 4, center: home});
            var maker = new google.maps.Marker({position: home,map: map});

        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZ6w4lQnt-YN_2SHLd4Y4Iu4M9NVut0k0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I expect the map to load and set a marker on the city of Kitchener,Ontario,Canada.

Comment: You should not be publishing your API keys here! (edit: this is the key used on the JSFiddle provided by Google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your function call `getElementById`: be away of the ending lowercase D.